# In what format is this date string?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, date-format, date-formatting, iso8601

Im trying to convert a bunch of NSStrings into NSDate objects. Here is an example string:

```
2013-04-25T15:51:30.427+1.00
```

But I can't figure out what format it is in, so far I have (The question marks are the bits I'm stumped with):

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss????zzz
```

The main problem I'm having is with the '.427' part although if I'm making a mistake elsewhere, let me know :)

Does anyone have any ideas? Or could point me to a list of all the possible date format specifiers? I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx which is useful but it doesn't appear to have any specifier for the '.427' part that I'm stuck on.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`.

See [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Also, the `ZZZZZ` format for the `+00:00` timezone format was added to iOS 6 and is not supported under iOS 5 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid date format as specified by ISO 8601, according to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

> The formats are as follows. Exactly the components shown here must be
>   present, with exactly this punctuation. Note that the "T" appears
>   literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time
>   element, as specified in ISO 8601.
>
> Year:
>         YYYY (eg 1997)    Year and month:
>         YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)    Complete date:
>         YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)    Complete date plus hours and minutes:
>         YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)    Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
>         YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)    Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
>   second
>         YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
>
> where:
>
> ```
>  YYYY = four-digit year
>  MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
>  DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
>  hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
>  mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
>  ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
>  s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
>  TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
> ```

In your case, the date has millisecond accuracy, try adding `.sss` to the format

Comment: These are not the proper format specifiers for use with an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: @rmaddy The question title, actually, says 'In what format is this date string?' and my answer does exactly that.

Comment: But the question is for iOS and tagged with NSDateFormatter. So the answer should be appropriate to that setting.