# How to parse the string "2013-06-13T05:47:03.737Z" to NSDate object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can i parse the string "2013-06-13T05:47:03.737Z" to an NSDate instance using NSDateFormatter? I've tried setting the dateFormat property of my dateFormatter to be:
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffZ", but i'm getting null. I hope U guys can help

Comment: Welcome to the site, this question has already been asked and answered here: [In what format is this date string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218855/in-what-format-is-this-date-string)  Please search before asking questions so that we don't end up with the same question over and over.

Comment: Where the heck did you come up with "fff"?  Did you even glance at the [date format guide](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```