# How to insert an NSDate into a column in an Azure managed database?

Tags: ios, azure, nsdate

If you have an Azure back-end, with a column that is a DateTime or DateTimeOffset, the example code is rather sparse about how you send a timestamp value as part of an insert.

You can pass along an NSDate in the dictionary of values to insert, and the library will translate it for you and insert is as a UTC/GMT timezone value.  However, my client specifically wanted this value to be in the timezone of the device which generated the data, which means I need to insert the value as a string, since NSDate has no inherent knowledge of timezones.

So...any suggestions on how to write the NSDate-to-string method?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

I changed my Azure Sql column datatype to *datetimeoffset* (which internally stores values as UTC *as well as the timezone offset*).

On client side I then used a date format *with **five** Z's*:

```
let date = NSDate() // local date time: Jun 27, 2014, 9:32 AM
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ" // Note 5 Z's...
let strNow = formatter.stringFromDate(date) // "2014-06-27T09:32:49+02:00"
```

I was then able to insert the date string "2014-06-27T09:32:49+02:00" to my Azure table in that format.

Querying my Azure table for that same inserted date I received back:

> 2014/06/27 09:32:49 +02:00

Comment: This is a better answer than my solution  :)

Comment: According to the official standard at http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns there is no "five z" pattern that is recognized, at most 4 Z is valid?

Comment: Found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218855/in-what-format-is-this-date-string) which says the 5Z format was added for iOS 6. It also [links](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) elsewhere in the standard you mentioned and there's a mention of ZZZZZ.

Spidey sense tingles slightly, but I've been successfully using 5Z in my app all day - looks like it's the way forward for me (if nobody else highlights a show-stopper).

Coincidently, it turns out my requirements are the same as per your original question, so this has been worthwhile ;-)

Comment: Cool!  I hadn't searched for 5Z since it wasn't in the main table!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two "gotchas":

1. The format is very specific for Azure to recognize and parse it correctly.
2. The required format is non-standard:  the 'Z' specifier produces a timezone offset such as -0700 or +0800 but Azure will reject it if there isn't a colon between the hours and minutes, ie, -07:00 or +08:00.  In the ARC solution below the colon is inserted after the string is generated.

(weird - format is a little off?)

```
+(NSString*)azureDateTimeString:(NSDate *)date
{
    static NSDateFormatter *df = nil;
    if(df == nil)
    {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] ;
        [df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
        df.timeZone =  [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"]; 
    }
    NSString *dateString =  [df stringFromDate:date];

    // insert a colon in the third position from the right of the string...
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-2], [dateString substringFromIndex:[dateString length]-2]];

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I found I had to append "Z" as a *literal* suffix rather than a timezone type indicator as part of the format string:

*(My Azure column is DateTime and I'm using Xcode Swift)*

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
let strNow = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

*= "2014-06-27T00:40:52Z"*

Note that I not only included 'T' as a literal but also 'Z'.

I could then successfully insert that date string into my Azure table and then, as a test, I could read it back and reverse it like this:

```
var creationDate = "2014-06-27T00:40:52Z"; //read back from azure table
let dtCreation = formatter.dateFromString(creationDate)
```

*= Jun 27, 2014, 12:40 AM"*

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was doing with the Z.  In my answer the Z is being used in the format string to append the local timezone offset from Zulu.  In your case, you are appending the literal Z to indicate the timezone as being Zulu, which is correct because you are not converting the default timezone to the local timezone.  If you read my question, the client specifically wanted the device timezone NOT zulu so your answer is not actually the answer to the question.

Comment: Aha, I see the problem now. Sorry about that. For my purposes I only needed to know the *actual* local time on the device when saving, no matter where it originated from. You're saying that you need the timezone offset included in the saved value *but* in a string format acceptable by an azure date column, right? I'll be interested in that solution as well. If I may impose upon you: how should my post be amended ito stackoverflow decorum? Should I delete my answer so as to not confuse any readers who come across this post?

Comment: "You're saying that you need the timezone offset included in the saved value but in a string format acceptable by an azure date column, right?" Yes, that was exactly it.   :-)

Comment: As for deleting your answer or leaving it, I'm not sure which is better.  :-)