# Converting date from xml to readable format

Tags: php, xml, date-formatting

I have a xml file, containing several dates, in this `format: 2016-07-23T07:00:00.000Z`. I'm using a php function to convert this in to a format for publishing on a website. This should actually result in something like `Saturday, 24th of July` (24th, not 23rd, because of the time offset. My function somehow ignores the `T07:00:00.000Z` part and thus returns `Friday, 23rd of July`. Can anybody help me out with the proper way to convert this date?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: What is your function? PHP has solid built-in date formatting support.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: And have you set the timezone correctly in your php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$oldDateTime= "2016-07-23T07:00:00.000Z"; // Your datetime as string, add as variable or whatever.
$newDateTime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

The string in question

```
2016-07-23T07:00:00.000Z
```

is [a W3C datetime format (W3C DTF)](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (*Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second*) which can be properly parsed incl. the fractions of a second with the `date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/date_create_from_format) function:

```
$originalDate = "2016-07-23T07:00:00.000Z";
date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $originalDate);
```

It does create a new  [**DateTime**](http://php.net/class.DateTime) which then can be formatted with the for PHP standard codes, e.g.

```
date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $originalDate)
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); # 2016-07-23 07:00:00
```

As that W3C format carries the timezone already and it is UTC, and you wrote you want a different one, you need to specify it:

```
date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $originalDate)
    ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'))
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The reason why this is not visible (and controlable with the code given) in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24329892/367456) is because [`date`](http://php.net/date) formats according to the [default set timezone in PHP](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) where as each **DateTime** has it's individual timezone.

An equivalent with correct parsing (incl. decimal fraction of a second) with the other answers then is:

```
$dateTime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $originalDate);
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTime->getTimestamp());
```

Hope this explains it a bit better in case you need the complete date value and / or more control on the timezone.

For the format, see as well: [In what format is this date string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16218855/367456)